# Convert Hibernate exceptions in Spring Roo to Spring Data Access exceptions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-roo

I am currently working on a Spring Roo project and I want the exceptions thrown by Hibernate to be converted to Spring Exceptions. E.g. I want the Hibernate exception ConstraintViolationException to be converted to Spring's DataIntegrityViolationException.

I have done this in Spring projects previously by adding in the following code to my Spring config:

```
<!-- Translates Hibernate exceptions to Spring Data Access Exceptions -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

However in Roo this does not work. Can anybody tell me how I can get this working and why it doesn't work in Roo?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? It is ignored? Another (different) exception is thrown? What?

Comment: @munyul The Hibernate exception is thrown. In my case the Hibernate ConstraintViolationException is thrown rather than the Spring DataIntegrityViolationException

Comment: is it possible that it is being "ignored" because it can't find the Exception class you've defined? The package + class is correct and Hibernate can find the JAR containing the class?

Answer (score 0):

You must setup the persistence layer as JPA Repository in order Roo configures your project to use Spring Data.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-layers.html#d4e1962